# Как узнать текущие координаты окна tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть окно созданное через tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Как получить координаты окна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на мой же вопрос:

```
print(root.geometry())
```

В таком случае tkinter выведет размеры окна и его координаты, выглядеть это будет так

```
{ширина}x{высота}+{координаты по "x"}+{координаты по "y"}
```

Comment: я совсем забыл написать.. если выводится неправдивая информация  по типу "0x0+0+0" то перед тем как получить геометрию окна пропишите root.update()

Answer (score 2):

У любого окна tkinter можно вызывать следующие методы:

```
winfo_x() - Х-координата окна
winfo_y() - Y-координата окна
winfo_width() - ширина окна
winfo_height() - высота окна
```